# ECONNRESET Request could not be proxied

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, web-deployment-project, cloud9

I am working on the answer model of my web app. When a user wants to answer a question he or she can click on the button. Instead of the expected behavior, I'm seeing [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tday4.png) in the terminal.

I am working with the online IDE Cloud 9 for Node.js.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Prasun! It's best to copy paste the error into a code block in your question rather that linking to a picture. If the link breaks in the future, others won't be able to benefit from your question.

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind.